# Storing associations to remote object using URI's

Tags: web-services, rest, distributed-computing, distributed-system

While working on a new application I came across a new, for me, scenario. Our identity system is a stand alone application with it's own data store only accessible though REST APIs. This is the theme we're moving forward with, independent apps that talk to each other through APIs.

Some entities in my new app have natural associations with identity entities on the IDM app.I can store a reference to that entity's Id as reported to my app through its API. I'm thinking it would be better to store the full URL where I can GET the entity.

Does anyone have suggestions on which way to go?

MyEntity
 - User: IDM issued ID

or

MyEntity
 - User: https://idm-server.com/users/{id}

Thanks in advance